# Getting egrep -o output in one line

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

We re trying to get only the data from the below output, we have tried to exclude the data with `egrep` command but the data which we get is in different line, how do i get the data in one line.

```
Total: 44.75TB   Used: 0.44TB    Available:42.04TB       Usage(5% System alocation included):6.07%
```

Here is the requirement

```
44.75   0.44    42.04       6.07
```

What we tried is this below command and the output

```
# cat output| egrep -o "[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]([eE][+-])?[0-9]"
44.75
0.44
42.04
6.07
```

Comment: try this
echo $(cat output | egrep -o "[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]([eE][+-])?[0-9]") | column -t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to get all values after `:` and join them using space or tab

`perl` is one option

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t",/:\h*\K[^ ]+/g' output
44.75TB 0.44TB  42.04TB 6.07%
```

- `/:\h*\K[^ ]+/g` will get non-space characters which are present after a `:` and optional horizontal spaces

  - use `\H` instead of `[^ ]` if the field separation can have tab characters
- `join "\t",` will join the matched strings with tab as separator

To get only numbers

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t",/:\h*\K[\d.]+/g' output
44.75   0.44    42.04   6.07
```

- assumes numbers with only digits and decimal point and doesn't check validity, it will match even `1.324.4`, `...` etc which comes after `:` and optional spaces

Comment: I want only the numbers not the `TB` & `%`

Comment: @Shanker your expected output was different initially.. anyway, from regex you used, do you expect scientific notation numbers in your input?

Answer (score 1):

We may treat the input line as several records, each record being delimited by two or more spaces.  Each record may be divided into two fields based on the colons and any single space after it. We want the second field in each such record.

With GNU `awk` (or `mawk`, but not `nawk` which does not like regular expressions as record separators):

```
$ awk -vRS="   *|\n" -vFS=": ?" -vORS=" " '{ print $2 } END { printf("\n") }' data.in
44.75TB 0.44TB 42.04TB 6.07%
```

- `RS="   *|\n"` sets the record separator to two or more spaces, or a newline. This splits `Total: 44.75TB   Used: 0.44TB` into two records, `Total: 44.75TB` and `Used: 0.44TB`.
- `FS=": ?"` sets the field separator to a colon, optionally followed by a space. This splits `Used: 0.44TB` into two fields, `Used` and `0.44TB`.
- `ORS=" "` sets the *output* record separator to a space.

The `awk` code simply prints the second field of each record separated by `ORS`, and finishes off by outputting a newline.

If you want to strip everything that is not a number from this, just pass it through `tr -dc '0-9. \n'`:

```
$ awk -vRS="   *|\n" -vFS=": ?" -vORS=" " '{ print $2 } END { printf("\n") }' data.in | tr -dc '0-9. \n'
44.75 0.44 42.04 6.07
```

`tr -dc '0-9. \n'` will delete anything that is not a digit, dot, space or newline.